# Need to add AD location Info in the script

Tags: powershell

I have a script for retrieving AD site and subnet info from the forest. Need to add the location details also to the script

The script is tested and working fine where it gives site and subnet details.

```
$configNCDN = (Get-ADRootDSE).ConfigurationNamingContext

$siteContainerDN = ("CN=Sites," + $configNCDN)

$siteObjs = Get-ADObject -SearchBase $siteContainerDN -filter { objectClass -eq "site" } -properties "siteObjectBL", name

foreach ($siteObj in $siteObjs) {

    $subnetArray = New-Object -Type string[] -ArgumentList $siteObj.siteObjectBL.Count

    $i = 0

    foreach ($subnetDN in $siteObj.siteObjectBL) {

        $subnetName = $subnetDN.SubString(3, $subnetDN.IndexOf(",CN=Subnets,CN=Sites,") - 3)

        $subnetArray[$i] = $subnetName

        $i++

    }

    $siteSubnetObj = New-Object PSCustomObject | Select SiteName, Subnets

    $siteSubnetObj.SiteName = $siteObj.Name

    $siteSubnetObj.Subnets = $subnetArray

    $file = "C:\temp\1.csv"

    Out-File $file -encoding ASCII -input $siteSubnetObj -append
}
```

I expect to pull out AD location details also using the script.

Comment: What attribute or property contains the location details you seek?

Comment: If you wish to get the DN then you can try this `$SysInfo = New-Object -ComObject "ADSystemInfo" ;
$ComputerDN = $SysInfo.GetType().InvokeMember("ComputerName", "GetProperty", $Null, $SysInfo, $Null) ;
$ComputerDN`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can shorten this script by using the `Get-ADReplicationSite` command. I would also consider using `Export-Csv` since you are outputting objects to file.

```
Get-ADReplicationSite -Filter * -Properties Subnets,Location |
   Select @{n='SiteName';e={$_.Name}},
   @{n='Subnets';e={$_.Subnets -replace "^CN=(.*?),CN=Subnets,.*$",'$1'}},Location |
   Export-Csv -Path 'C:\temp\1.csv' -encoding ASCII -NoTypeInformation
```

`Export-Csv` will create a comma delimited file by default (the delimiter is changeable) with the first line (headers) being the property names of your objects. Each other line will contain comma separated values for each of those properties. The columns for properties and values will line up perfectly.

If you have more than 4 subnets per site, the `Out-File` method alone without changing anything else will cut off the subnet values. You would need to set `$formatenumerationlimit` to something higher than 4 or -1 for unlimited or make sure the output is not in table format. It will be much harder to work with this file if you don't use `Export-Csv` because there will not be a consistent delimiter between item properties and their values.

I can add location details to this if you explain exactly what that is.

Comment: I'm also not sure about the Location Parameter. Below script helps to pull out the location details of a single site. Pls. use the below helps.

--------------------------------
$siteName =  "Site"
$configNCDN = (Get-ADRootDSE).ConfigurationNamingContext
$siteContainerDN = ("CN=Sites," + $configNCDN)
$siteDN = "CN=" + $siteName + "," + $siteContainerDN
Get-ADObject -Identity $siteDN -Properties "Description", "CN", "siteObjectBL", "Location"

Comment: @ShijinMohammed I've updated the code to include location

Answer (score 0):

I do not know what are you referring to with "Location" so can't help there. 
Also, I understand the file output is easier to read that way and is probably consumed by a human as a report but you have to consider `Out-file` will default to your screen width when redirecting to file so the number of subnets which will be saved will depend on that width (and not on a fixed value such as 4). To enlarge the output width you can use the `-width` parameter

```
$Something | out-file $file -width 600
```

or set the default width:

```
 $PSDefaultParameterValues=@{"Out-File:Width"="600"}
```

Note that large numbers may have undesired side effects.